# Merging from df1 to df2 on same column - expanding dataset out

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am making a small mistake and I'm not sure how to merge two df correctly. I want to merge on IBES_cusip to get gvkey into df1.

I try the following, but it just expands the dataset out and does not match correctly:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', on =['IBES_cusip'])
```

**df1**

```
       IBES_cusip       pends pdicity  ... ltg_eps  futepsgrowth 
0        00036110  1983-05-31     ANN  ...     NaN           NaN  
1        00036110  1983-05-31     ANN  ...     NaN           NaN  
2        00036110  1983-05-31     ANN  ...     NaN           NaN  
3        98970110  1983-05-31     ANN  ...     NaN           NaN  
4        98970110  1983-05-31     ANN  ...     NaN           NaN  
          ...         ...     ...  ...     ...           ...      
373472   98970111  2018-12-31     ANN  ...   10.00      0.381119  
373473   98970111  2018-12-31
```

**df2**

```
         gvkey IBES_cusip
0       024538   86037010
1       004678   33791510
2       066367   26357810
3       137024   06985P20
4       137024   06985P20
       ...        ...
833796  028955   33975610
833797  061676   17737610
833798  011096   92035510
833799  005774   44448210
833800  008286   69489010
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Which one? I had a look through Pandas Merging 101 before and wasn't sure which one would work

Comment: I went through that before and the merging I used was based off that. It is not working and that's why I reached out with this question

Comment: Ok, what your expected output?

Comment: IBES_cusip is in both. I just want the gvkey in df2 to be in df1 with the same IBES_cusip

Comment: lets try `pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left')`

Comment: Tried that, mapping and joining and they all did not work

Comment: For one column, you can do `map`: `df1['gvkey'] = df1['IBES_cusip'].map( df2.set_index('IBES_cusip')['gvkey'] )`.

Comment: Also, once you say *they all did not work*, you should definitely say **in your question** why that was the case. Did they throw some error? Did they produce unexpected output? etc.

Comment: The map you provided raised this error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that your `df2` contains duplicate values in `IBES_cusip` column.
from the sample you gave I can see that

```
3       137024   06985P20
4       137024   06985P20
```

are the same values, this would cause the to get unwanted results (duplicate rows in the output).
try this

```py
df1 = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['IBES_cusip']), how='left', on='IBES_cusip')
```

Which should technically just add a `gvkey` column to your `df1`.

> This assumes that you are pretty sure that you don't have rows with the same `IBES_cusip` that are matched with different `gvkey` otherwise you need to figure that out first.

Comment: Ahhh! Perfect. My mistake. Thanks for the help! :)